# Moduli space of genus 2 curves

Tags: moduli-spaces, ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, curves

Does any body know any reference in which the geometry of compactified moduli space of genus two curves ( Which is a three dimensional variety/stack/...) has been studied?

Comment: In response to some comments, my question is about complex curves only. No non-zero characteristic discussion please.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Genus 2 curves are hyperelliptic and so their coarse moduli space is just the Riemann-Hurwitz space $(\mathbb{P}^1)^6/(SL_2 \cdot S_6)$. So the description of $M_2$ is closedly linked with the invariants of binary sextic forms. The classic reference is the paper

J. Igusa, [Arithmetic Variety of Moduli for Genus Two](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970233), Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 72, No. 3 (1960), pp. 612-649.

Brendan Hassett's paper [Classical and minimal models of the moduli space of curves of genus two](http://math.rice.edu/~hassett/papers/genus2/logmodel3.pdf) is also a nice paper studying explicit compactifications for $M_2$ and their birational geometry properties.

Comment: Dear J.C., the description of $M_2$ in terms quotient space of $(\mathbb P^1)^6$ is valid only in characteristic different from $2$. But Igusa worked in any characteristic and even over $\mathbb Z$. 

Answer (score 11):

I recommend part III, the case g=2, of Mumford's ":Towards an enumerative geometry of the moduli space of curves", in the Shafarevich 60th birthday volume.

Answer (score 8):

Over the complex numbers, you might be interested in: Mostafa:Die Singularitäten der Modulmannigfaltigkeit $\overline M_g(n)$ der stabilen Kurven vom Geschlecht $g\geq 2$ mit $n$-Teilungspunktstruktur. (German) [The singularities of the moduli variety $\overline M_{g}(n)$ of stable curves of genus $g\geq 2$ with $n$-division point structure] J. Reine Angew. Math. 343 (1983), 81–98.

Over a field of any characteristic, in my [paper](http://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~liu/articles/courbes_stables_genre2.pdf) § 3, the scheme $\overline M_{2}$ over $\mathbb Z$ (and over any field $k$) is described as the normalization of the blowup of the weighted projective scheme
$$\mathrm{Proj}\mathbb Z[J_2, J_4, J_6, J_8, J_{10}]/(J_4^2-J_2J_6+4J_8)$$
(the $J_i$'s are Igusa invariants and have weight $i$) along some explicit center. The singularities over $k$ are described as well.

Answer (score 1):

For a birational viewpoint:

W. Rulla, The birational geometry of $\overline{M}_{3}$ and $\overline{M}_{2,1}$, Ph.D. thesis, University of Texas at Austin,
2001.