# Moduli space of abelian surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, abelian-varieties, finite-fields

Let $K$ be a finite field with algebraic closure $\overline{K}$. The $j$-invariant gives a bijection between the the affine line $\mathbb{A}_K^1$ and $\overline{K}$-isomorphism classes of elliptic curves defined over $K$. In other words, $\mathbb{A}_K^1$ is a coarse moduli space for $\overline{K}$-isomorphism classes of elliptic curves defined over $K$.

My question is: does there exist a similarly nice (although obviously not as nice) description of the coarse moduli space of $\overline{K}$-isomorphism classes of abelian surfaces defined over $K$?

For general abelian varieties, it seems the moduli space (at least within an isogeny class) is given by so-called "Dieudonne modules" (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00229.pdf), for example). I'm hoping that the surface case might admit a simpler description, just as the curves case did.

Comment: Generally when studying moduli problems it useful to attach a polarisation to the varieties. So the corresponding problem here would be the moduli space of principally polarised abelian surfaces. The generic such surface is the Jacobian of a curve of genus 2, so this moduli space plays a key role. Some the references here may be useful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76585/moduli-space-of-genus-2-curves .

The coarse moduli space is also a rational variety, as proved by Igusa in the paper in the cited answer.